# OpenCSW and IPS on same Solaris 11 system?

Tags: package-management, solaris, ips

Is there any danger running both IPS and OpenCSW side by side on a single Solaris 11 system?

I assume there should be no conflicts since both package managers use different repositories and different installation paths and it would just add twice the updates since there are twice the package managers. However I just want to make sure since I come from a Red Hat background and I am a little bit cautious about having two package managers running side by side.

Comment: Back in the OpenSolaris days, I had installed a large amount of OpenCSW packages on one of my file servers, and it didn't conflict with the `ips` packaging used by OpenSolaris at all.  And I haven't dug into the specifics, but I've installed Sys V packages (older, Solaris 10 and earlier packaging system) on Solaris 11 boxes with no issues.  So even the older Sys V packaging system seems to coexist with the `ips` system just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably some note on OpenCSW's site, but my guess would be as long as they don't try to overwrite each other, or conflict with the other library files (ie: linker), it'd probably be ok.  However, I'd hope the folks at OpenCSW are careful to not do that based on building pkgs for Solaris.  I'm unable to access the OpenCSW site to read their docs -- site possibly blocked.